# How to use firewall between two docker networks inside one physical server

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I want to use docker network like DMZ and internal network on a physical server.

`docker network create DMZ ...
 docker network create Internal ...`

Now I want to allow **only** 3306/tcp to DMZ to internal traffic. I know docker network doesn't allow each network to access each other, but actually both can 
access through the bridge network. Or, I would be able to use one more network that both networks could access. I guess I can make the virtual DMZ and internal network environment if I can place a firewall container between the networks, or use a firewall service on containers in either network. I tried to use firewalld inside the container but it doesn't work.

What is a good practice to use docker networks like DMZ and internal? I also want to know about the swarm case. Any suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: I didnt get the point that you mentioned about both networks can access through bridge network. I would put the DMZ network having internet access and create internal network with "internal" flag that prevents outside access.

Comment: @Sreeni Sorry it's not the main point, please forget about the bridge network. I just need a firewall in front of the `--internal` network, not outside the server. Do you have any idea?